# почему не работает запрос(дата)

Tags: sql, postgresql

Мне нужно Найти имена всех работников, принятых на работу до 1988 года
делаю такой запрос:

```
SELECT name
FROM SalesReps
WHERE hire_date < '1988'
```

Ошибка: Invalid input syntax for type date: "1988" LINE 3: WHERE hire_date < '1988'
дата представлена в базе таким образом: 1999-12-12

Comment: Ну проблема в том, что вы тип даты сравниваете с типом строки. Посмотрите в документации date_part функцию и другие для работы с датами
`date_part('year', hire_date) < '1998'`

Comment: Дату нужно сравнивать с датой. Т.е. год преобразовать в дату. Для чего преобразовать "до 1988 года" в "до X числа Y месяца Z года"

Comment: @DmitriiSedov ну нужно тут перебирать всю таблицу и выдирать год из каждой даты, это не эффективно

Comment: @teran ну я как пример привел, а так вы правы конечно, можно просто указать `< '1998-01-01'`